# Getting column info from db with C#

Tags: c#, mysql

In PHP I am able to retrieve information from a db like so:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
```

I am trying to acomplish the same thing in C#:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = @id");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", id);
        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            data.Add("id", reader.GetString(0));
            data.Add("username", reader.GetString(1));
            data.Add("firstName", reader.GetString(2));
        }
        return data;
```

Is it possible to reference the column in the table by name without going through all this trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [OdbcDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdataadapter.aspx) class to populate a `DataSet`, which would probably be a bit simpler.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to use this?

Comment: Also a lot less efficient. -1 for actually recommending something as stupid as a DataAdapter where all the world moves to efficient DAL's.

Comment: like Unkwntech asked, could you please provide an example. I'm slightly confused.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but it is SLOW. Not slower than your approach, granted, but slow - I would mark your whole code for a review...

- Dont ask for "*", ask for the fields. Good SQL practice - and as you know the fields, guess what, you dont ahve to guess them. On top, you assume id is fiel 0, username field 1...

If that is not possible - read the docomentation. There is a "GetOrdinal" method that takes a field name and.... returns.... the field index.

That said, this whole code is fully redundant. Have a look at proper data access layers, or at least BLTOOLKIT - you can move all that code into ONE abstract method with the rest being automatically generated.

Comment: I think its safe to assume that the SELECT * is likely just example code.  Also, I think its safe to assume that not every person who has looked at the docs saw everything there was to see.

Comment: No, but looking at the docs two times WHEN YOU LOOK FOR SOMETHING is common sense. Too lost those days.